# ASP.NET - Get next value in databound list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm databinding a List of strings and I know how to obtain the current string in the DataItem being used by the `_ItemDataBound` function using `(String)e.Item.DataItem`, but I want to know if there's a way to get the next `DataItem` that the function is going to use.

I'm trying to avoid setting the List as a global variable.

EDIT: Here is an example of my actual code since I currently don't have access to the PC with the actual code.

**Repeater.aspx**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGeneral" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Repeater.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater repeat = rptGeneral;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //I'm obtaining the questions from my database
        //connection, dataReader and other sql variables are here
        List<String> list = new List<String>();
        while(dataReader.Read())
        {
            list.Add(dataReader["questionName"].ToString());
        }
        dataReader.Close()
        repeat.DataSource = list;
        repeat.DataBind();
    }

}

public void rptItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        String question = (String)e.Item.DataItem;
        String nextQuestion; //get the next DataItem
        Label lblQuestion = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblQuestion");
        lblQuestion.Text = question;
    }
}
```

Comment: plz post your code too..!

Comment: Is it really necessary? It's a simple string list being databinded but oh well, I'll post a example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the next item in the repeater's OnItemDataBound event as the ItemDataBound event triggers just after binding the current data item from the data source items. Some of the work around solutions for this could be

1. Make the data source as the class level variable. In the OnItemDataBound event find the next item in the data source. (of course you mentioned, you dont want to do this)
2. Instead of binding string list, you can bind custom object list. The object can contain two properties CurrentValue and NextValue. Before bindng into repeater you have to build up this list and bind it. Then you can access both in the OnItemDataBound event.
3. Another approach would be that, After calling DataBind function, loop through the repeater items and do the actions you want to perform, for exmple setting next value to some controls etc.